# Error on testing connection with Mysql Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    //This class is for testing connection with mysql database 
    class JDBCTest {
    // path to database is stored in string url

        private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";

    // username is stored  in string root

        private static final String user = "root"; //username

   // password is stored in string password 

       private static final String password = "swapnil";//password

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
//i have stored driver in c:\javap\
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                System.out.println("Success");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("hi");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

whenever I try to run this program I get the exception
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

I am using mysql database my operating system is windows 7 64 bit. I have included the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin in jdk/jre/lib/ext` I have also set up the `CLASSPATH` Environment variable but nothing work me out

Comment: You need to add jdbc mysql jar in your classpath. It contains the driver implementation.

Comment: check classpath in your test : System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

Comment: i have added System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

Comment: i have added this line System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));in my sample code after setting the classpath =.;c:\javap\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar; in environment varialbles. but when i run the program i get the output "." (dot)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should not put anything under the JDK's jre/lib/ext directory.

Instead, use the `-cp` option when launching your application, and make sure to have the **jar** of the driver (and not the bin directory) in the classpath:

```
java -cp mysql-xx.jar;... com.foo.bar.JDBCTest
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL is incomplete use:

`private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename";`

also as @JB Nizet mentioned do not put jars in jdk's lib.